# why stl choose tree based map instead of hash based map?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary

I'm wondering why STL's map is base on rb tree?
I mean, hash-based map seems to be more efficient in inserting/deleting or even getting the value.
Are there any specific considerations?

Comment: I can only guess that the tree can guarantee a good time complexity while a hash-based map can produce very poor results depending on the hash function and the input

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The STL *originally* chose both. It had a hash table *and* the tree-based map.

However, when it was adopted into the standard, many parts were stripped away in order to simplify the task (it was easier to talk the committee into including a smaller library, and it required less work in terms of actually specifying their behavior).

So the hash table was skipped.

However, both data structures have their advantages. In particular, a binary tree allows the contents of the map to be *ordered* (you can iterate over the contents of a map in sorted order, or you can ask for all elements smaller than a specific element, for example), and I can only guess that this property was considered more important than the performance advantages of a hash map.

However, in C++11, `std::unordered_map` is added, which is the long lost hash table. Its original omission was simply due to time pressure and, quite possibly, committee politics (keeping the library small to minimize resistance against it)

Comment: This doesn't explain why Stepanov (presumably) named his tree-based map "map" and the hash map "hashmap" (it's only named `unordered_map` for historical/political reasons now), and it also doesn't explain why the std committee originally choose the tree-based map, and ditched the other — but it does explain the history, so it gets a `+1` from me.

Comment: Well, keeping the library small is a point, but leaving out a data structure as fundamental as a hash table has always made me shake my head over the standard comittee's decision. Finally after years they have corrected this error and for me `std::unordered_map` (and it's colleagues), as basic it may be (or rather because of that), is one of the most important features of C++11's library additions. But enough of the subjectivity, +1 for the actual answer, of course ordered maps have their advantages, too.

Comment: @Christian: The (late) incorporation of the STL into the std lib already delayed the standard by at least a year, maybe two. Everyone involved was aware that they were cutting important stuff, but they also wanted to finally release a standard, rather than work a second decade on it until publishing what would have been perfect a decade before. You need to know that back then every compiler came with its own stream library, all of which were slightly incompatible. And we had about half a dozen popular container and/or algorithm libs. Given this, the standard was heaven-sent the way it was.